# Generate combinations of groups in pandas Series or DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` set up like this:

```
 Type     time
 A        0
 A        1
 A        2
 B        0
 B        1
 B        2
```

I need to generate a list (or a Series) structured as follows:

```
["A.1-A.0", "A.2-A.0", "B.1"-"B.0", "B.2"-"B.0"]
```

Would `groupby` or similar functions would be able to generate such a list (or Series)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data =  StringIO("""Type     time
A        0
A        1
A        2
B        10
B        11
B        12""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, dtype="O")

def set_first(x):
    x["ptime"] = x.time.values[0]
    x = x[1:]
    r = x.Type + "." + x.time + "-" + x.Type + "." + x.ptime
    return r

print df.groupby(df.Type, group_keys=False).apply(set_first)
```

output:

```
1      A.1-A.0
2      A.2-A.0
4    B.11-B.10
5    B.12-B.10
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up implementing something very similar to this.